Template function, VS 2022 compiler seems to only implement argument version that was called first
I'm trying to create a templated function which can take either a Boost ptime, or time_duration - in order to extract the hours and format them as "00:00".
It is seeming that the compiler will only implement the template function under the type that was called first (in main()). Any further calls with another type will fail in compilation, saying xyz function cannot be used with type x.
Is there a way to make this template function work, or am I asking too much of the C++ compiler here?
Here's the code:
template <class T>
std::string GetHHMM(T TS) {
    int HH, MM;
    time_duration td(0, 0, 0);  // Our working variable that will contain either the time_duration argument, or a converted ptime argument.
    // If it's a ptime, we need to get the time out and put it in the time_duration variable.
    if (typeid(TS) == typeid(ptime)) {      // Just a check...picking up ptime argument OK.
        std::cout << "GetHHMM got called with a ptime." << std::endl;
        td = TS.time_of_day();  // Error C2039 - if main calls this function with a time_duration first
        HH = td.hours();
        MM = td.minutes();
    }
    if (typeid(TS) == typeid(time_duration)) {  // Just a check...picking up time_duration argument OK
        std::cout << "GetHHMM got called with a time_duration." << std::endl;   // Picks up time_duration argument OK
        HH = TS.hours();    // Error C2039 - hours is not member of ptime (thinks TS is a ptime when it's not, due ptime called first in main())
        MM = TS.minutes();
    }
    std::string s = str(boost::format("%02d:%02d") % HH % MM);
    return s;
}

In main() I've tried 'forcing' (not sure if that's the right term) the compiler to make both editions (one for time_duration, and one for ptime) with a call like:
GetHHMM<ptime>(p1) and GetHHMM(time_duration)

but no go. The compiler is only to happy to implement the function for whatever argument I called first in main(). I was hoping shifting compilation to C++17 would help (I believe it does has improved template interpretation), but no go there either. I'm using VS 2022 C++.

All the paths through function needs to be equally valid. It seems to me that what you really want is specialization. Or just plain overloading.

if (typeid(TS) == typeid(ptime)) is a runtime check. It seems like you want if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, ptime>) instead. But please show a complete [mre]. The order of use in main is not relevant.

I actually recommend that you use overloading, with one function taking a ptime argument, do the time_duration conversion, and then calls the common time_duration overload.

Thanks guys, yes I think I need specialization or overloading. And also, @Some Programmer Dude, I think you put your finger on what I'd struggled to understand but detected was out there somewhere: the type checking is only at run time, too late!

@user17732522 - I included the main() calls as I was thinking (hoping?) I could force implementation for both types using the  expression in the call. But I will look into the constexpr as a solution, thanks again.

You almost always want an overload, not a specialisation. See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

The entire function needs to typecheck regardless of the type T.
You could solve that with a compile-time if constexpr, but then you would also need to handle unexpected types (e.g. GetHHMM(123) and GetHHMM("hello") would compile with your code).
There is no point in reaching for templates here - overloading makes the code much simpler.
Example:
std::string GetHHMM(time_duration td) {
    return str(boost::format("%02d:%02d") % td.hours() % td.minutes());
}

std::string GetHHMM(ptime ts) {
    return GetHHMM(ts.time_of_day());
}


Gotchya, back to where I started that worked ok with overloads, but thanks molbdnilo and others who pointed this out: an overload sounds like the best way to deal with this issue, rather than trying to template things that shouldn't really be templated. (I was getting carried away on templating as there were only a few lines different between the different functions). I'll look into the constexpr approach too, which may be appropriate for functions where the majority of the code in the previously overloaded functions is the same.
